# How to apply an image from ACR to App service using Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am new to devops and struggling to deploy an ACR image to a windows web app in app service.
I have created a basic ADO pipeline which should build and push the docker image to ACR, and deploy it to the App service
The pipeline is running fine, no errors reported but its not actually deploying anything to the web application.

when I access the application, it says its running and waiting for content.

The deployment step is below:

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4

  inputs:

  ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'

  azureSubscription: 'xxxx'

  appType: 'webAppHyperVContainer'

  WebAppName: 'xxx'

  ResourceGroupName: 'xxxx'

  DockerNamespace: 'xxxx.azurecr.io'

  DockerRepository: 'xxxx'

  DockerImageTag: 'latest'

The application image is uploaded fine to ACR by the pipeline and in the application configuration setting, DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME is correctly set, but nothing is being deployed to the web app

Any pointers on what I am missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to repro the same and got similar issue when I'm passing the correct image with **invalid tag** from the azure devops task.
Please check below things to resolve the issue.

Make sure you are passing valid image with proper tags and must **exist in the container registry before deployment task started**.
To verify deployment on web app, check the deployment history in app service kudu portal > site > deployments.

[image]

[image]

Verify the logs of the app service whether the image is pulled correctly or not.

[image]

Make sure the following configuring settings are present in your app settings configuration.
DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME

DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD

DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL

DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME

WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE

[image]

After following all the above steps, I will be able to access web page deployed.

[image]